# Regular Expression for a single occurrence within a String

Tags: regex

I am new to Regular Expression and can't seem to do the proper syntax for what I need to do.  I need regular expression for an alphanumeric string that can be 1-8 characters long and can contain at most 1 dash, but can't be a single dash alone.

Valid:

```
A-
-A
1234-678
ABC76-
```

Invalid:

```
-
F-1-
ABCD1234-
---
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add what you have tried

Comment: "What have you tried" is not relevant for regex questions.

Answer (score 3):

Try this regex:

```
/^(?!([^-]*-){2})[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,8}$/
```

- `^ and $` are to match start and end.
- `(?!([^-]*-){2})` is a lookahead that makes sure that matching pattern has only one hyphen in it at the most.
- `[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,8}` match 1 to 8 alpha-numerals or -

**Reference:** http://regular-expressions.info

Comment: Pretty sure there needs to be a dash in that character class.

Comment: Matches `-` but won't match `aBc` (at most 1 dash, minimum 0 ?)

Answer (score 3):

One way. (Sorry if this is already posted)

```
 #  ^(?=[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,8}$)(?=[^-]*-?[^-]*$)(?!-$).*$

 ^                              # BOL
 (?= [a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,8} $ )      # 1 - 8 alpha-num or dash
 (?= [^-]* -? [^-]* $ )         # at most 1 dash
 (?! - $ )                      # not just a dash
 .* $
```

**Edit:** Just extend it for segments separated by comma's

```
 #  ^(?!,)(?:(?=(?:^|,)[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,8}(?:$|,))(?=(?:^|,)[^-]*-?[^-]*(?:$|,))(?!(?:^|,)-(?:$|,)),?[^,]*)+(?<!,)$


 ^                         # BOL
 (?! , )                   # does not start with comma
 (?:                       # Grouping
      (?=
           (?: ^ | , )
           [a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,8}         # 1 - 8 alpha-num or dash
           (?: $ | , )
      )
      (?=
           (?: ^ | , )
           [^-]* -? [^-]*            # at most 1 dash
           (?: $ | , )
      )
      (?!
           (?: ^ | , )
           -                         # not just a dash
           (?: $ | , )
      )
      ,? [^,]*                  # consume the segment
 )+                        # Grouping, do many times

 (?<! , )                  # does not end with comma
 $                         # EOL
```

**Edit2:** If your engine doesn't support lookbehinds, this is same thing but without

```
 #  ^(?!,)(?:(?=(?:^|,)[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,8}(?:$|,))(?=(?:^|,)[^-]*-?[^-]*(?:$|,))(?!(?:^|,)-(?:$|,))(?!,$),?[^,]*)+$


 ^                         # BOL
 (?! , )                   # does not start with comma
 (?:                       # Grouping
      (?=
           (?: ^ | , )
           [a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,8}         # 1 - 8 alpha-num or dash
           (?: $ | , )
      )
      (?=
           (?: ^ | , )
           [^-]* -? [^-]*            # at most 1 dash
           (?: $ | , )
      )
      (?!
           (?: ^ | , )
           -                         # not just a dash
           (?: $ | , )
      )
      (?! , $ )                 # does not end with comma

      ,? [^,]*                  # consume the segment
 )+                        # End Grouping, do many times

 $                         # EOL
```

Comment: The 2nd answer is working great for what I asked, but I left out a part of the requirement (I thought if I got the first part, the 2nd part would be easy).  The requirement is a comma separated list of the String that I described.  So, the can do:
A-z,-Q,123-

I tried to do:
/^((?=[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,8}$)(?=[^-]*-?[^-]*$)(?!-$).*)(,(?=[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,8}$)(?=[^-]*-?[^-]*$)(?!-$).*)$/
Taking where the answer left off, but I obviously do not understand how this is processed, because my answer is not working at all.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I have a similar one that is simpler...It allows for a comma separated list of 2-3 alpha characters.  It's regex is: /^[/*A-Za-z]([A-Za-z]{1,2})(,[/*A-Za-z]([A-Za-z]{1,2}))*$/

Comment: I am reading  /^((?=[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,8}$)(?=[^-]*-?[^-]*$)(?!-$).*) as "The first 1 up to 8 characters must be alphanumeric or dash".  This is probably why I cannot do 4 characters and then a comma for my next item.

Comment: @user3006614 - Posted a method for segmentation. Be carefull when modifying the regex. Its all done in the assertions, have to stay consistent.

Comment: I very much appreciate your help on this...I do not have the knowledge to write this type of regex.  I am still encountering an error.  I am running EXTJS code on Chrome and IE breosers.  When I instantiate my object that has the regex, I get the following error: 

Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^(?!,)(?:(?=(?:^|,)[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,8}(?:$|,))(?=(?:^|,)[^-]*-?[^-]*(?:$|,))(?!(?:^|,)-(?:$|,)),?[^,]*)+(?<!,)$/: Invalid group 

Any ideas?

Comment: @user3006614- No, there is no syntax error. You must have pasted in error. Try it on one of the online testers.

Comment: Or, just re-type it. Sometimes SO injects extra/invalid characters.

Comment: Or, maybe your engine doesn't support lookbehind assertions.

Comment: Try the one without lookbehind. (Edit2)

Comment: @user3006614 - How did you make out on this? Btw, Use **Edit2** code because I don't think JavaScript supports lookbehind assertions, Edit2 fixes that.